# Jquery Modal Overlay with PHP insert success

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to display a jquery modal overlay if an HTML form successfully inserts the form data into my database.

i.e. if the form data is inserted, it displays a "success!" modal overlay, otherwise it displays a "sorry, your post was not uploaded." modal overlay.

How would I use PHP to check if the data were inserted or not?

Extra credit: can I then just put the modal overlay code inside an if/else statement after that PHP check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Submit the form via Ajax and then call the modal if the Ajax returns success.

Comment: OK, this makes sense.  I will try this shortly.  Thanks Nathan!

Comment: Can I do multiple conditions within AJAX?  For instance, if it fails, am I able to check for multiple conditions as to why it failed 
(using AJAX)?

Comment: Yes you can return any message you like from AJAX. You can have a success function and an error function too.

Comment: It may take awhile to figure out how the ajax calls work but it is worth it in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You should post the data to PHP through an Ajax method call and based on the value returned from the server, you can customize the message and show it in a modal dialog box.